Как запустить скрипт из другого скрипта, если они не на одном объекте и не дочерние?
Я пока новичок в C# так что прошу совета.
Мне нужно чтобы скрипт с камеры (игрока) запускал другой скрипт на другом объекте (GameObject).
Я не могу засунуть камеру(игрока) под другой объект(GameObject).
Может получиться через GetComponent?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Например так:
// Найти объект по имени
GameObject go = GameObject.Find("MyObject");
// взять его компонент
SomeGoComponent someComponent = go.GetComponent<SomeGoComponent>();

Дальше работать с someComponent

А можно в Inspector один объект поместить в поле другого, при этом у второго скрипта должно быть это поле прописано как публичное:
public SomeExternalComponent ec;

Далее в Inspector у этого скрипта впихиваем нужный объект. Как пример:


Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Попробовал но не получилось выводит ошибки

Я так понимаю озвучивать их вы не собираетесь и нужно вас уговаривать это сделать?

Вот код
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotation_on_holl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;
    private SomeGoComponent;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(signal3))
        {
           print("jnjn");
           anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
           anim.enabled = true;
           GameObject go = GameObject.Find("GameOb"); 
           SomeGoComponent someComponent=go.GetComponent<GamePlay();
           SomeGoComponent.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}


Извините просто только недавно начал пользоваться платформой ещё не освоился

Выводит ошибки CS1002 и CS1525

Я не знаю все тысячи номеров ошибок наизусть. у них есть имя и тело, в котором чётко написано что это за ошибка и в чём заключается

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1002    ......... https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1525
